# Is there a global way to set a datetime to GETDATE() when an UPDATE is performed?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database model where each and every table has a `datetime` field named _CDateTime.

When a row is `INSERT`ed a default value of `GETDATE()` is written by SQL Server to this field.

When an `UPDATE` is issued on a row on the other hand the _CDateTime field is not automatically updated by SQL Server.

I know that I could use the `timestamp` date type, but that doesn't convey any time information (contrary to it's name).

Another solution would be to write a trigger for each and every table, but that is much work.

So the question is: Is there any global way that works like a global trigger that fires when a row is updated in one of the database tables and automatically sets the _CDateTime field to the current date and time?

PS: The answers to this question suggest that there is no such thing: [Multi table Triggers SQL Server noob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619937/multi-table-triggers-sql-server-noob)

Comment: In short: No... fortunately. Even triggers are normally too much "magic".

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Why fortunately? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff: Here are some points: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/24/sql-server-disadvantages-problems-of-triggers/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809/sql-server-2000-is-there-a-way-to-tell-when-a-record-was-last-modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need either an UPDATE trigger to apply getdate() to the _CDateTime field or you must submit _CDateTime = getDate() on each single update. There is no automatic way of doing that